# Некорректное отображение интерфейса на других устройствах

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlayout

Должно отображаться вот так:

[image: как должно]

---

Отображается на другом компьютере вот так:

[image: как есть]

**main.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(606, 433)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 340, 111, 41))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 50, 261, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 300, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Допустим кнопка"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Большая и длинная надпись"))

class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.world)

    def world(self):
        self.lineEdit.setText("Hello, world!")


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Handle high resolution displays:
    if hasattr(QtCore.Qt, 'AA_EnableHighDpiScaling'):
        QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling, True)
    if hasattr(QtCore.Qt, 'AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps'):
        QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps, True)

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Dialog()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Вот это я находил для решения данной проблемы, но не помогает:

```
# Handle high resolution displays:
if hasattr(QtCore.Qt, 'AA_EnableHighDpiScaling'):
    QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling, True)
if hasattr(QtCore.Qt, 'AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps'):
    QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps, True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваши проблемы связаны с тем, что на устройствах разные шрифты и вы используете абсолютное позиционирование.

Вы можете поправить положение дел, добавив

> void QWidget::[**adjustSize()**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.ht)
>
> Регулирует размер виджета в соответствии с его содержимым.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(606, 433)
        
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 340, 111, 41))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 50, 261, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 300, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Допустим кнопка"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Большая и длинная надпись"))


class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.world)
        
        self.label.setStyleSheet("#label {background-color: #ccffbd;}")  
        self.label.setText("Большая и длинная надпись1234567890")
        self.label.adjustSize()

    def world(self):
        self.lineEdit.setText("Hello, world!")
        
        self.label.setText("Большая и длинная надпись 12345678901234567890")
        self.label.adjustSize()
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Dialog()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Лучшие практики рекомендуют использовать [**менеджеры компоновки**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) и у вас никогда не будет таких проблем.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(606, 433)
        
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 340, 111, 41))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 50, 261, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 300, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Допустим кнопка"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Большая и длинная надпись"))


class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.world)
        
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
        self.label.setStyleSheet("#label {background-color: #ccffbd;}")  
        self.pushButton.setFixedSize(133, 41)
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(20, 30, 20, 30)
        layout.setSpacing(30)
        layout.addStretch(1)
        layout.addWidget(self.label, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addStretch(1)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, alignment=Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignBottom)        
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton, alignment=Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignBottom)

    def world(self):
        self.lineEdit.setText("Hello, world!")
        
        self.label.setText("Большая и длинная надпись 12345678901234567890")   
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Dialog()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

А теперь попробуйте изменять размеры окно в обоих вариантах и  почувствуйте разницу.

Comment: Менеджеры компоновки лучше сразу делать в Qt Designer, да?

Comment: @Arkadjan да, это можно сразу делать в Qt Designer.